# DC voltage at the output of push pull stage

Tags: mosfet, output, current-mirror

I have an output stage. The circuit diagram is as shown:

[image]

In DC condition, the node X has a DC voltage of Vdd/2. The node Z has a voltage of about 1.26 volts. Vdd = 3.3 volts. Transistors M7 and M5 have same W/L and so is the case with M6 and M8. The current through both the branches is the same around 50 uA. Both X and Z nodes are unloaded, i.e open. Now here are my questions:

1. Why does node X settle to vdd/2?
2. Why node Z does not settle to vdd/2?

Here is my attempt at the solutions:

1. Considering the output branch, Id will be the same through M7 and M8, if both are in saturation then the standard equation \$ I_d = K(Vgs-Vth)^2 \times (1+\lambda Vds) \$.
   Since Id is the same, Vgs for both the transistors is 1 volt, \$\lambda \$ is negligible because the channel length of both the transistors is long. What remains is the factor K and Vth. Unfortunately i cannot find the technology values hence I would like to know whether this analysis is correct so that i can blindly blame K and Vth :). If that is true then somehow all the values come together in the branch with node X to get X at vdd/2.
2. Second line of thought are the caps Cds of M7 and M8. they are in series and using the capacitor voltage divider rule, the voltage at node Z and similarly for ode X can be estimated. I checked the capacitance but the voltage at node Z and X do not check out with this theory.

Any help will be appreciated.

Edit:
Also if i consider the first line of thought, that since Id is the same in the output branch, therefore M7 and M8 will force the voltage at node Z such that Vds for both transistors are enough for the current of 50 uA to flow. If thats the case, then what needs to be changed (w/l, bias current) to get node Z to vdd/2

Comment: Is there a load connected? If so, what impedance?

Comment: @BrianDrummond No there is no load connected, like i mentioned in the post, both Xand Z are open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it’s not a classic AB stage. The front end is more like AB because it is a push pull source follower and has a gain of unity AND will exhibit close-to-mid-rail performance.

The output stage on the other hand has a massive voltage gain that will exploit any subtle differences in the MOSFETs. It’s not an AB stage at all.

Comment: Yup correction made

Comment: Ok the gain is really high, because its an inverter stage, but still can you please  explain why the voltages?

Comment: Differences between p and n channel MOSFETs.

Comment: OK, but i am trying to figure out what difference causes it, is it the small signal resistance, or the Cds of both the mosfets, given equal Vgs

Comment: Also while talking about DC voltages, do AC parameters really matter?

Comment: No, AC parameters don’t matter provided you have done a proper steady state analysis.

Comment: Try looking at Vgs(threshold) values and also note that if this is a real circuit there could be significant variations between seemingly identical parts. Also consider leakage currents.

Comment: Ok, but if Vgt(vgs - vt) of pmos is lower than that of nmos, that only means pmos turns on faster, but since the current is the same through both devices, how would Vgt affect output voltage

Comment: Faster implies speed and this is not what happens at do. Threshold is a DC phenomenon. Are you simulating or building your circuit?

Comment: I am simulating

Comment: Back to the same problem after an year, what are the possible ways to make vout=vdd/2 ?